# IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, array-broadcasting

```
a=np.arange(240).reshape(3,4,20)
b=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
c=np.zeros((3,4),dtype=int)
x=np.arange(3)
y=np.arange(4)
```

I wanna get a 2d (3,4) shape array by the following step without loop.

```
for i in x:
    c[i]=a[i,y,b[i]]
c
array([[  0,  21,  42,  63],
       [ 84, 105, 126, 147],
       [168, 189, 210, 231]])
```

I tried,

```
c=a[x,y,b]
```

but it shows

`IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (4,) (3,4)`

and then I also tried to establish `newaxis` by `[:,None]`, it also doesn't work.

Comment: "I also tried to establish newaxis by [:,None] it also doesn't work." Always post the exact thing you try, since this approach (when done correctly) works as per answer below...

Comment: You want a (3,4), and `b` has that shape.  The other indices must broadcast to the same shape.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
>>> a[x[:,None], y[None,:], b]
array([[  0,  21,  42,  63],
       [ 84, 105, 126, 147],
       [168, 189, 210, 231]])
```

#### Discussion

You tried `a[x,y,b]`.  Note the error message:

```
>>> a[x, y, b]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast
            together with shapes (3,) (4,) (3,4)
```

The `(3,)` means that we need to extend `x` to have 3 as the first dimension and 4 as the second dimension.  We do this by specifying `x[:,None]` (which actually allows `x` to be broadcast to any size second dimension).

Similarly, the error message shows that we need to map `y` to shape `(3,4)` and we do that with `y[None,:]`.

#### Alternative style

If one prefers, we can replace `None` with `np.newaxis`:

```
>>> a[x[:,np.newaxis], y[np.newaxis,:], b]
array([[  0,  21,  42,  63],
       [ 84, 105, 126, 147],
       [168, 189, 210, 231]])
```

`np.newaxis` is None:

```
>>> np.newaxis is None
True
```

(If I recall correctly, some earlier versions of `numpy` used a different capitalization style for `newaxis`.   For all versions, though, `None` seems to works.)

Answer (score 1):

Similar but different, *hard coded* not generic.

```
>>> b = np.ravel(a)[np.arange(0,240,21)]
>>> b.reshape((3,4))
array([[  0,  21,  42,  63],
       [ 84, 105, 126, 147],
       [168, 189, 210, 231]])
>>>
```